# Incorrect URI encoding of Excel hyperlinks

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an application that is tasked with changing the values ​​in selected cells in an Excel sheet. Unfortunately, after changing values in some cells, the URI encoding of Excel hyperlinks changes to a different format, replacing national characters and spaces, making them corrupted (also in other sheets where the data was not changed).

The scheme of the application's operation is as follows:

```
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream (excelSourcefile);
    long length = excelSourcefile.length ();
    byte [] content = new byte [(int) length];
    in.read(content);
    in.close();
    ...
    String filePath = serverPathToTempDirectory;
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile (new File (filePath), content);
    ...
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (filePath);
    // so far I see a new Excel file with correct hyperlinks in temp dir

    // set new value (1.0) to cell (2,2) in sheet test
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("test");
    Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(2);
    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue(1.0);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook.write(bos);  
    workbook.close();
```

In the source Excel file in drawing.xml.rels, the example relationship node looks like this:

```
<Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink" Target="#'Rach.Bież. (miesięcznie) '!B3"/>
```

After executing workbook.close() statement the same node looks like this:

```
<Relationship Id="rId2" Target="#'Rach.Bie%C5%BC.%20(miesi%C4%99cznie)%20'!B3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink"/>
```

References to the same tabs in sheet.xml files are properly encoded. The problem exists only with drawings hyperlinks.

To reproduce this issue you can create an Excel file (e.g. C:\Test\src\test.xlsx) with three sheets:

- "test" - with value 0 in A1 cell
- "test with space" - may be empty
- "btn" - with any image with link to A1 cell in "test with space" sheet,

create empty C:\Test\dest directory and you could run below method. When the code executes, in the directory C:\Test\dest there should be a file with the value inserted in the "test" tab and with a broken link related to the image in the "btn" tab.

```
    private void test() throws IOException
    {
        String path = "C:\\Test\\src\\test.xlsx";
        File excelSourcefile = new File(path);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(excelSourcefile);
        long length = excelSourcefile.length();
        byte[] content = new byte [(int) length];
        in.read(content);
        in.close();
        
        String filePath = "C:\\Test\\dest\\test.xlsx";
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(filePath), content);
        
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(filePath);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("test");
        Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(1.0);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(bos);  
        bos.close();
        workbook.close();
    }
```

Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: You could just use `Files.copy();`. Also as I see it, this question has nothing to do with apache-poi, as your issues seem to happen before you even open the workbook in the application.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my problem ... and sorry for the confusion. After changing the data, the target file overwrites the source file and in this test described originally, the source file was the file in which the hyperlinks were previously broken. The problem occurs when editing cells - the problem description has been corrected.

Comment: The only thing that I see that could be an issue is that you are not closing the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. You should try `workbook.write(bos); bos.close(); workbook.close();`. If that doesn't help, you will need to provide code that replicates the issue

Comment: Closing `ByteArrayOutputStream` doesn't change anything. I added to the above problem description a method that should replicates the issue.

Comment: The issue is that the link gets HTML encoded. Currently I don't know where this happens and if there is a code workaround. However, you could use no spaces/special characters in the sheet names to not have this issue

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an easy solution. What you could attempt, is to delete the relationship and recreate it in the hopes to not have it encode. The encoding happens during the opening of the workbook, yet it doesn't seem to decode it during saving. As a matter of fact, they deliberately skip the relationship files in `org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage#saveImpl()` method. The comment is `If the part is a relationship part, we don't save it, it's the source part that will do the job.` though I can't tell where the "source part" saves anything

Comment: My application only changes data in files created by customers so it is not up to me what the sheets will be named.

Comment: I also tried to remove hyperlinks and recreate them but while trying to create a link with a space I got an error: `Invalid target - java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in fragment at index 31: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml#'test with space'!A1`. Nevertheless, thank you for your time spent analyzing this issue.